# Trouble with RedirectToAction moving from ASP.NET MVC 5 to ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm migrating from ASP.NET MVC 5 to ASP.NET Core and I'm having trouble with `RedirectToAction`.

I'm setting the RouteValues to `new { Test = "Hello World" }`.

But when it gets to my `ActionFilterAttribute`, the `ActionExecutingContext.RouteData.Values["Test"]` is null.

What am I missing?

Application Startup:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env,
        ClarityUserManager userManager,
        SignInManager<ClarityUser> signInManager)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("ContentRootPath", env.ContentRootPath);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("WebRootPath", env.WebRootPath);
    }
```

Controller:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Something()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { Test = "Hello World" });
    }
}
```

ActionFilter:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class SessionExpireAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var test = filterContext?.ActionDescriptor?.RouteValues["Test"];
        // test is null
        var test2 = filterContext.RouteData.Values["Test"];
        // test2 is also null
    }
}
```

Home:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public HomeController()
    {
    }

    //
    // GET: /Home/
    [SessionExpire]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try the solution and feel free to share if you need any further assistance on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When it gets to my ActionFilterAttribute, the
> ActionExecutingContext.RouteData.Values["Test"] is null. What am I
> missing?

First of all, you cannot get the query parameter from your `filterContext?.ActionDescriptor?.RouteValues`, you have to check in `httpContext` instead. Because, `new { Test = "Hello World" }` would not consider as valid route rather query. If you even want to get as route value then you have to change the defination here  `pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");` and have to introduce a parameter in your `Index()` action like this `Index(string test)` only then you can get as `RouteValues["Test"];`

In addition, even you want to get the query value from your `"Index", "Home"` at the first request it will always be empty because in that request our query value has not yet assign. It will only assigned when `Something()` action within  `SomeController` will be invoked.

**Way to Get  `Test = "Hello World"` From Action Filter:**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class SessionExpireAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
           
            var actionMetadata = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Query["Test"].GetValue();
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]